# play an segments of audio file and synchronise with moving line on graph

Tags: matlab, audio, vector, matrix, graph

I m having audio wav.I plot a graph of audio wav vs time of audio wav.
I have some points for ex: 4 points .I plotted a vertical line on the graph at this 4 points. 
from this 4 points on graph I made 5 segment.audio file start time is 1,and end time is 10;

```
a=[1 4 7 9];

s=
     start-time    end-time
s1      1             4
s2      4             7
s3      7             9
s4      9             10
```

Now i want to play the segment at the same time line should move synchronously from start-time of segment and stop at end-point of segment.